# How to use Webpack with Angular + templateCache?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I'm learning Webpack. I made an App with Angular and I use templateCache to generate all my html views in one js file than require in App. It works cool. But then the Webpack job:

```js
entry: {
    app: ["bootstrap-webpack!./bootstrap.config.js", './app/app.js'],
    vendor: ['angular', 'bootstrap', 'angular-ui-router', 'oclazyload']
},
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: '/bundle.js'
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(
        /* chunkName= */ "vendor", /* filename= */ "/vendor.bundle.js"),
```

That was the part of my webpack config. As the result I get directory "dist" with "bundle.js" && "vendor.bundle.js" and index.html. After that I start server and my App says that it can't GET views. Why? :( As I understand all my views have to be bundled and should be available in the "dist" directory.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I do not use the `templateCache` at all. Since Angular directives also accept a template as string, I just `require()` the template with the [html-loader](https://github.com/webpack/html-loader).

```
function MyDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        template: require("./MyDirective.html")
    };
}
```

---

```
// in your webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.html$/, loaders: ["html"] }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks; a team-member pointed out this approach to me today after futzing around with various template cache loaders. Do you know why so many template loaders exist even though we can simply inline templates like this?

Comment: They probably don't know ^^. There is a lot of stuff unnecessarily complex with AngularJS 1.0. If you don't see the benefit of dependency injection, for instance, the whole module system is cruft

Comment: Template loaders exist so that you can pre-compile templates and make them available @ run time, as opposed to compiling them at run time as this approach entails.

Comment: We actually use a few of our templates in different components/directives. This approach would probably duplicate that code which a templateCache approach wouldn't. I like the fail-fast-ness of this approach though!

Comment: Using the html-loader will not duplicate the HTML code. The module will only be included once.

Comment: If you use the same template for several components (for any reason), that will be duplicated. Also The disadvantage of this approach is that you need to rewrite all your entrances of templateUrl -> template if you are migrating to webpack your existent project

Comment: Sorry, this is not correct. The HTML source code is definitely included only once. If you're using code-splitting, it could be that the HTML will be in included in several chunks, but that applies to all modules in webpack.

Comment: Regarding the templareUrl > template comment. Yes, that's correct. But I assume that you could do find & replace with a regexp to do that. Furthermore, it reduces the load time because the template is instantly available.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, the template just renders as `[object Object]`

Comment: Note that it should now be `loaders: ["html-loader"]`

Comment: This doesn't work with third party libraries that only accept templateUrl such as ui-bootstrap

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Being a beginner on `Angular` I was spending my time figuring out these shiny `loaders`. This answer saved me.

Answer (score 11):

Its late but might as well share this. If you really want to use html fragments maybe for

```
<div ng-include="'file.tplc.html'"></div>
```

here is how I made it work

```
var appMod = angular.module('app'); 

appMod.run(function($templateCache) {

    function requireAll(requireContext) {
        return requireContext.keys().map(function(val){
            return {
                // tpl will hold the value of your html string because thanks to wepbpack "raw-loader" **important**
                tpl:requireContext(val),

                //name is just the filename
                name : val.split('/').pop()
            }
        });
    }

    // here "../" is my app folder root
    // tplc is the naming convention of the templates
    let modules = requireAll(require.context("../", true, /\.tplc\.html$/));

    modules.map(function (val) {
        $templateCache.put(val.name, val.tpl);
    })

});
```

Comment: Just for clarification: Is your code triggered by calling "webpack" or on starting the application?

Comment: `require.context` is triggered by `webpack`. The rest of the function will run once the app has been bootstrapped with the contents (another function) returned by the context function.